# Scraping data from website using Beautiful Soup and show it in jinja2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, beautifulsoup, jinja2

I am trying to pull list of data from website using Beautiful Soup:

```
class burger(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    Husam = urlopen('http://www.qaym.com/city/77/category/3/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%B1/%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%AC%D8%B1/').read()

    def get(self, soup = BeautifulSoup(Husam)):

        tago = soup.find_all("a", class_ = "bigger floatholder")
        for tag in tago:
        me2 = tag.get_text("\n")

        template_values = {
                           'me2': me2
                           }
        for template in template_values:

            template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Now when I try to show the data in template using jinja2, but it's repeat the whole template based on the number of list and put each single info in one template.

How I put the the whole list in one tag and be able to edit other tags whith out repeating?

```
<li>{{ me2}}</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To output a list of entries, you can loop over them in your jinja2 template like this:

```
{%for entry in me2%}
  <li> {{entry}} </li>
{% endfor %}
```

To use this, your python code also has to put the tags into a list.

Something like this should work:

```
   def get(self, soup=BeautifulSoup(Husam)):
      tago = soup.find_all("a", class_="bigger floatholder")

      # Create a list to store your entries
      values = []

      for tag in tago:
          me2 = tag.get_text("\n")
          # Append each tag to the list
          values.append(me2)

      template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')

      # Put the list of values into a dict entry for jinja2 to use
      template_values = {'me2': values}

      # Render the template with the dict that contains the list
      self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

References:

- [Jinja2 template documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates)